How to hide the Advanced settings and Print using system dialogue in virtual printer in chrome print dialog?
I am using Angular to create a Chrome extension and in that, I am adding a virtual printer to the Chrome printer dialogue in that I want to hide the Advanced settings and Print using system dialogue options from my code.
Please find below my printer configuration.
var capabilities = {
    version: "1.0",
    printer: {
        supported_content_type: [{
            content_type: "application/pdf",
            min_version: "1.5",
        }, {
            content_type: "image/jpeg",
        }, {
            content_type: "text/plain",
        }, ],
        input_tray_unit: [{
            vendor_id: "tray",
            type: "INPUT_TRAY",
        }, ],
        marker: [{
            vendor_id: "black",
            type: "INK",
            color: {
                type: "BLACK",
            },
        }, {
            vendor_id: "color",
            type: "INK",
            color: {
                type: "COLOR",
            },
        }, ],
        cover: [{
            vendor_id: "front",
            type: "CUSTOM",
            custom_display_name: "front cover",
        }, ],
        color: {
            option: colorOptions,
        },
        duplex: {
            option: duplexOptions,
        },
        page_orientation: {
            option: layoutOptions,
        },
        custom_dropdown: {
            option: customDropdownOptions,
        },
        copies: {
            copies: 1
        },
        "staples": {
            title: "Staples",
            type: "SELECT",
            selected: 0,
            options: [{
                name: "None",
                value: 0
            }, {
                name: "Top Left",
                value: 1
            }, {
                name: "Top Right",
                value: 2
            }, {
                name: "Bottom Left",
                value: 3
            }, {
                name: "Bottom Right",
                value: 4
            }]
        },
        vendor_capability: "MEDIASIZE",
        media_size: {
            option: paperSizeOptions,
        },
        dpi: {
            option: [{
                horizontal_dpi: 600,
                vertical_dpi: 600
            }, {
                horizontal_dpi: 1200,
                vertical_dpi: 1200
            }, ],
        },
    },
};

Let me know if there is way to hide these options.
I have searched for configuration to hide the Advanced settings and Print using system dialogue but couldn't find any.
Need to hide these options - Advanced settings and Print using system dialogue


An important point to note right off the bat: this window is browser-specific functionality.
Google Chrome has an API through which you can implement exactly the same window.
The only implementation option I can think of is to use https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/printing to implement a custom print interface.
Basically js does not provide a way to customize what you are asking.
